# Save and re-load a weighted graph from OSMnx for NetworKX

Tags: networkx, osmnx

I am using OSMnx to get a graph and add a new edge attribute (w3) representing a custom weight for each edge. Then I can successfully find 2 different shortest paths between 2 points using NetworkX and 'length', 'w2'. Everything works fine, this is my code:

````
G = ox.graph_from_place(PLACE, network_type='all_private', retain_all = True, simplify=True,truncate_by_edge=False) ``` 
w3_dict = dict((zip(zip(lu, lv, lk),lw3)))
nx.set_edge_attributes(G, w3_dict, "w3") 
route_1 = nx.shortest_path(G, node_start, node_stop, weight = 'length')
route_2 = nx.shortest_path(G, node_start, node_stop, weight = 'w3')
````

Now I would like to save G to disk and reopen it, to perform more navigation tasks later on. But after saving it with:

```
ox.save_graph_xml(G, filepath='DATA/network.osm')
```

and reopen it with:

```
G = ox.graph_from_xml('DATA/network.osm')
```

my custom attribute w3 has disappeared. I have followed the [instructions](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.io.save_graph_xml) in the docs but with no luck. It feels like I'm missing something really obvious but I don't understand what it is..

Comment: try to use `edge_attrs` parameter

Comment: How do I get a graphml file? I want one of a specific city.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `ox.save_graphml` and `ox.load_graphml` functions to save/load full-featured OSMnx/NetworkX graphs to/from disk for later use. The save xml function exists only to allow serialization to the `.osm` file format for applications that require it, and has many constraints to conform to that.

```py
import networkx as nx
import osmnx as ox
ox.config(use_cache=True, log_console=True)

# get a graph, set 'w3' edge attribute
G = ox.graph_from_place('Piedmont, CA, USA', network_type='drive')
nx.set_edge_attributes(G, 100, 'w3')

# save graph to disk
ox.save_graphml(G, './data/graph.graphml')

# load graph from disk and confirm 'w3' edge attribute is there
G2 = ox.load_graphml('./data/graph.graphml')
nx.get_edge_attributes(G2, 'w3')
```

Comment: Yes, the attribute is there! But the values of my dictionary are now seen as strings, while before saving they where floats. I worked it around extracting the dictionary and converting strings to floats, but I was wandering what is the reason of this change.

Comment: OSMnx has to make some concessions to gracefully serialize everything to graphml format. Stringification is one of them.

Comment: Just what I was looking for, since I wanted to save a city to graphml.